# Access 2007 Linked Table Manager Disabled for One User - and Error 8458

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an Access front-end database connected to various back-ends (Access, mySQL, dBase) which runs as a separate instance on each users computer. All users have Access 2007, and there are a total of 5 users for this system. Each user runs the database from their local hard-drive.

On one computer I am unable to open any of the linked tables and receive error message 'Unexpected error from external database driver (8458)'. Also, I notice that the Linked Table Manager is disabled (grayed out) when right-clicking on the table link definitions.

Oddly, if I create a blank Access database on this computer, I can create and open linked tables with no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following "fix" from Microsoft if you have not yet.

Start Windows Explorer, and then browse to the **Borland** folder.

If you cannot locate the folder, follow these steps. *NOTE: Because there are several versions of Microsoft Windows, the following steps may be different on your computer. If they are, see your product documentation to complete these steps.*

- Click **Start**, and then click **Search**.
- Click **All files and folders**.
- In the All or part of the file name box, type **Borland**.
- In the Look in list, click **My Computer**.
- Click **Search**.

Rename the **Borland** folder as **BorlandOld**. (For example, rename *C:\Borland* as *C:\BorlandOld*.)

Comment: Funny, I saw this suggestion on the [Microsoft kb article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306095) and initially thought it did not apply. The article states it was a problem with AC2000, and foolishly I assumed this computer had no Borland software since no other users did. Turns out Borland drivers were present, and the fix applies to AC 2007 as well. Suggestion worked.